# My Keyboard stopped working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard

I use a dual boot of windows and Ubuntu and my keyboard suddenly stopped working on my Ubuntu, but it works fine on my Windows.

Comment: If you're dual-booting with Windows then you must disable Windows' Fast Startup feature. Please do that and shutdown Windows before booting Ubuntu. Ant difference?

Comment: It didn't fix the problem. I still can use the keyboard. The back light on the keys are active when I type on the keyboard, but it doesn't do anything on screen. I can only use onscreen keyboard.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to type? Doesn't the password work?

Comment: It's not working anywhere. Right from login, I can only type only using on screen keyboard. The keyboard lights up when I type and it also works well on my windows.

Comment: Then try a live session where it likely will work as expected. That being the case it's unlikely anyone can suggest a troubleshooting other than a full reinstallation.

Comment: I've already backed up and planning on reinstalling in a few hours. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

1. Press a Shift key during boot to get the GRUB menu.
2. In GRUB, select Advanced Options, then the first kernel with the recovery
   mode.
3. Select "Network" to get network access (needed for package installation)
4. Select "Drop to root shell"
5. Press [Enter] to confirm.

Taken from this comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-doesn%E2%80%99t-a-keyboard-work-sometimes-on-Ubuntu/answer/Adam-Baroumand?ch=10&oid=80459690&share=edb6f43d&target_type=answer